# Scrollbar + any scroll widget bug on scrolling in web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I need to use Scrollbar widget for web as it enables scrollbar always on AND the ability to edit its size and width. I also have to use it with a child that is scrollable (singlechildescrollview, listview, etc), but after updating to flutter 2.2, I've seen that 2 scrollbars appear on screen and keeps buging the experience (can be seen when changing the size of the scrollbar in the parent).

I've tryed to disable the scrolling in the child, but its scrollbar still shows. I cant use the default scrollbar in the child, as its more geared towards mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using rawascrollbar. It removes any padding when pressing on the side of the screen, and gives the ability to change the color of scrollbar (that way hides the child scroll). Better then the Scrollbar widget.